# How to translate php curl_setopt to ruby equivalent?

Tags: php, ruby, curl, translate

I need some help translating a php script to ruby

The php script:

```
$apiUrl = 'http://someurl/' . $_POST['type'];
unset($_POST['type']);

$fields = $_POST;
$fields['ip'] = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$fieldsString = http_build_query($fields);

$ch = curl_init();

////set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
'Api-Key: somekey'
));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $apiUrl);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fieldsString));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fieldsString);
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($fields);
////execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);
////close connection
curl_close($ch);
exit;
```

the ruby code I've done so far..

```
postparams = {
    'sent_from'         => 2,
    'id'                => @client.id,
    ...etc...
    'type'              => type,
    'ip'                => request.remote_ip
}

apiUrl = "http://someurl/#{type}"
fields = postparams

#$fieldsString = http_build_query($fields);
fieldsString = fields.to_query

#$ch = curl_init();
easy = Curl::Easy.new
#curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER, true);

# curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
#     'Api-Key: somekey'
# ));
easy.headers = ["Api-Key: somekey"]
#curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $apiUrl);
easy.url     = apiUrl
#curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fieldsString));

#curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fieldsString);
res = easy.http_post(apiUrl, fieldsString)

#$result = curl_exec($ch);

render :text => res.inspect
```

So the questions are:

- how do I translate #curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fieldsString));
- how do I translate #curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
- will easy.http_post perform what I intend to? that is posting the params with given header optons, etc...
- any other suggestions

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how do I translate #curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER, true);

Like this:

```
 easy.header_in_body = true
```

> how do I translate #curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,
>   count($fieldsString));

The php curl_setopt() docs say:

> CURLOPT_HTTPGET   TRUE
>
> to reset the HTTP request method to GET. Since **GET is the default**,
>   this is only necessary if the request method has been changed.

In other words if you write:

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, FALSE);
```

the request defaults to a get request.  So...

```
http_method = (postparams.length==0) ? 'get' : 'post'
easy.http(http_method)
```